# Создать рандомные числа и присвоить их каждому индексу в списке (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, list, случайные-числа

не так давно приступил к изучению пайтона, да и в целом программирования. Пока читал одну из глав книги о списках и кортежах, мне пришла в голову идея: написать код, который будет через библиотеку random генерировать произвольные числа от 0 до 10000. Затем сгенерированное число будет поочередно присваиваться каждому индексу в списке (предположим, что имя у списка будет myList и хранить он в себе будет значения [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. После всех этих операций значения в списке будут рассортированы через метод sort() и выводиться на экран. Такую задачу я пытался решить, но ничего не получилось. Спасибо за помощь.

```
import random

myList = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

for item in myList:
   myList[item] = random.randint(1, 10000)

print(myList)
```

Comment: Что значит "не получилось", где ваш код?

Comment: В принципе, это элементарная задачка, которую можно написать в одну строчку, но если кто-то напишет её за вас, вы ничему не научитесь.

Comment: Не могу на данный момент предоставить код

Comment: упд. Добавил код

Comment: Вам нужно внимательно перечитать главу и списках и циклах.

Comment: Вы всё время присваиваете значения элементу myList[0]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем коде достаточно заменить

```
for item in myList: --> for item in range(len(myList)):
```

и все внезапно заработает, вы проходитесь по элементам, а потом вызывает список от элемента, а не от индекса, конечно ничего не работает.

Но вашу задачу проще было бы решить через генератор списков:

```
my_list = [random.randint(0, 10**4) for i in range(5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
from random import randint
 
random_number = [random.randint(0, 10000) for i in range(5)]
print(random_number)

myList = sorted(random_number)
print(myList)
```